# How to define observational equality in Agda

Tags: equality, agda, injective-function

Let's say I have a render function:

```
rasterize : ℕ → ℕ → Tile → List (List Color
```

I need to prove this statement:

if `rasterize w h t1 = rasterize w h t2` then `t1 ≡ t2`

in other words if t1 and t2 render to the same value given the same width and height, then they are equal.

I dont know how to say this in agda, I came up with the following:

```
obs-eq : ∀ (t₁ t₂ : Tile) (w h : ℕ) →
  rasterize w h t₁ ≡ rasterize w h t₂ → t₁ ≡ t₂
```

but I suspect this is not what I mean and from googling around I think I need to define an operator that compares the rendered values? Also some kind of sigma type is involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parenthesization is wrong: when you write

```
obs-eq : 
  ∀ (t₁ t₂ : Tile) (w h : ℕ) →
  rasterize w h t₁ ≡ rasterize w h t₂ → 
  t₁ ≡ t₂
```

it means that if I give you any two tiles and any two dimensions, such that the tiles rasterize to the same picture *at those dimensions*, then you can prove that they are equal.

Consider what happens if I choose `w = 0` and `h = 0` for you...

But what you want to say is that if I give you any two tiles, and a proof that *for any two dimensions* they rasterize to the same picture, *then* you can prove that the tiles are equal:

```
obs-eq : 
  ∀ (t₁ t₂ : Tile) →
  (∀ w h → rasterize w h t₁ ≡ rasterize w h t₂) → 
  t₁ ≡ t₂
```